# How do find the last added ID in a non auto incremented table?

Tags: sql-server, identity

How do I get the ID of the last added element in the? From my searching on the web I found that you can use @@IDENTITY and IDENTITY_SCOPE() but only while adding them/being in the. I tried the following but it isn't working

```
CREATE TABLE Products
 (PT_ID int PRIMARY KEY, Name nvarchar(20))

 CREATE TABLE Storage(ST_ID int Primary key,Info nvarchar(20))

 CREATE TABLE ProductStorageMM
 (ST_ID int CONSTRAINT S_FK FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Storage(ST_ID ),
 PT_ID int CONSTRAINT P_FK FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Products(PT_ID ),
 Status int not null,
 PRIMARY KEY (ST_ID ,PT_ID )
 )
```

The tables above are just for the experiments sake.I am trying to, when adding a value into the Product table automatically set all the values of the given product in The storages to zero.

```
     CREATE PROCEDURE AddingProduct 
     (@PID int ,@NAME nvarchar(20))
     AS BEGIN
     INSERT INTO Products(PT_ID,Name)
     VALUES(@PID,@NAME)

     INSERT INTO PSKT (PT_ID,ST_ID,Status)
     SELECT PTT.PT_ID ,STT.ST_ID,0
     FROM (SELECT * FROM Storage) AS STT, 
          (SELECT * FROM Products WHERE PT_ID=SCOPE_IDENTITY()) AS PTT;

 END
```

The Procedure doesn't work.What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `@@IDENTITY` is for Microsoft SQL Server. Your question is tagged MySQL. Which one of them are you actually using?

Comment: In MySQL you should be using MAX() to find the last added ID

Comment: @MattGibson Ah, sorry I didnt notice that. I am using sql server

Comment: @RaymondNijland cCant use max because the IDs arent in order

Comment: Easy answer: no, you can't get the last ID you added in SQL Server unless you have an IDENTITY column. But then, you already know the ID. It's `@PID`.

Comment: You can use output inserted for getting last entry's value and that id you can insert into another table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am I missing something?  Isn't @PID  the last identity used?  @@IDENTITY and SCOPE_IDENTITY are used for auto-increment identities.  You're not showing auto-increment here, you're passing the identity in to the procedure.  This inserts a row into PSKT for the @PID passed in with every row in STORAGE.

--> Given code where identity is passed in through a parameter

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddingProduct 
     (@PID int ,@NAME nvarchar(20))
     AS BEGIN
     INSERT INTO Products(PT_ID,Name)
     VALUES(@PID, @NAME)

     INSERT INTO PSKT (PT_ID,ST_ID,Status)
     SELECT @PID ,STT.ST_ID,0
     FROM Storage STT

 END
```

--> Example using auto-increment and @@identity

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddingProduct 
     (@NAME nvarchar(20))
     AS BEGIN
     INSERT INTO Products(Name) --< identity is inserted through auto-increment
     VALUES(@NAME)

     set @pid = @@identity  --< we need to get the identity created in the previous step for the next step.

     INSERT INTO PSKT (PT_ID,ST_ID,Status)
     SELECT @PID ,STT.ST_ID,0
     FROM Storage STT
```

END

Comment: I tough you could use identity without auto-incremented IDs

Comment: No, @@identity returns the last auto-incremented identity.  When using auto-increment, you don't know what identity was created.  In your case, you know the identity so why would you want to call a function to get it?